# How can I set the label frame while I rotate the iPad in simulator

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I am new to iPad development. Here, I have a tableview with dynamic content. Each cell contains two labels, second label may increase or decrease. Finally I am adding the labels to cell. But when I rotate the simulator the labels in cell are not changing. I cannot set the frame for label. Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

```
UILabel *label1 = nil;
UILabel *label2 = nil;

NSLog(@"it decides the tablecell");
UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"] autorelease];

    label1 =[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 200, 44) ];
    //label1 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    [label1 setLineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    [label1 setMinimumFontSize:FONT_SIZE];
    [label1 setNumberOfLines:0];
    [label1 setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:FONT_SIZE]];


    label2 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    [label2 setMinimumFontSize:FONT_SIZE];
    [label2 setNumberOfLines:0];
    [label2 setLineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    [label2 setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:FONT_SIZE]];


}
NSString *text1 = [arrOutline1 objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
NSString *text2 = [arrOutline2 objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];



CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake((CELL_CONTENT_WIDTH - (CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN * 2))/ 2, 20000.0f);

CGSize size1 = [text1 sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:FONT_SIZE] constrainedToSize:constraint lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
CGSize size2 = [text2 sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:FONT_SIZE] constrainedToSize:constraint lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];


[label1 setText:text1];
[label2 setText:text2];

    [label1 setFrame:CGRectMake(CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN, CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN-10,( CELL_CONTENT_WIDTH - (CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN * 2))/2, MAX(size1.height, 44.0f))];

NSLog(@"now it is in cell methd");
UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;
if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft||orientation==UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight)
{
    [label2 setFrame:CGRectMake(300 , CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN - 10,500 , MAX(size2.height, 44.0f))];
    NSLog(@"orientation is :LAndscape");
    //[[cell contentView] addSubview:label2];
    [cell addSubview:label2];

}
else
{
    NSLog(@"orientation is Portrait.");

    [label2 setFrame:CGRectMake(300 , CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN - 10,200 , MAX(size2.height, 44.0f))];
    [cell addSubview:label2];


}
    //[label2 setFrame:CGRectMake(300 , CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN - 10,( CELL_CONTENT_WIDTH - (CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN * 2)) /2 , MAX(size2.height, 44.0f))];




cellHeight =size2.height + 44;

label1.backgroundColor =[UIColor clearColor];
label2.backgroundColor =[UIColor clearColor];


[[cell contentView] addSubview:label1];
[label1 release];
[label2 release];

return cell;

}



- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {

[TableOutline reloadData];
return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to resize your subviews automatically when the iPad rotates?

1) Make sure that your parent view (inb your case I guess the table view cell) has `autoresizesSubviews` set to YES (This will be the default)

2) Make sure that the labels you add have the correct value set for the `autoresizingMask` e.g.

```
// To keep label1 the same size and have label2 stretch to fill the rest of the cell . . .
[label1 setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin];
[label2 setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];
```

Here, you have set label 1 to be a fixed distance from the left hand side and be a fixed width. You have set label two to be a fixed distance from the left and right but have a variable width. When your table cell's frame changes, it will automatically change the frames of the labels inside it.